# Duplicates in depth first search algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, duplicates, graph-algorithm

I'm writing a program in Java where I must implement three search algorithms, among the three is the depth first graph-search algorithm. My program traverses a connected graph represented internally by an adjacency matrix and uses a frontier and an explored set with each algorithm.

The frontier stores the unexplored child nodes of expanded parent nodes and the explored set stores those nodes which have actually been expanded. The purpose of the explored set is to avoid duplicates and thus avoid infinite loops.

My frontier is implemented using a linked blocking deque and my explored set using a linked hash set.

However, upon testing the initial version of this algorithm implementation I noticed that there were still a small number of duplicates, particularly when the goal node did not exist and the algorithm would surely have to visit every node in the graph. Eventually I realized that this is because when a node is expanded all of its child nodes are added to the  frontier but only one of them is explored. Because the graph is a connected one then other paths may exist to the node and this may result in the node being encountered multiple times before it is ever expanded and thus added to the explored set.

This leads me to my question, do i fix it?

The depth first search is supposed to explore one side of the tree formed from the graph first and then backtrack, this means that even if it encounters a less optimal goal node on one side of the tree it should return that instead of a (more optimal) one previously encountered but not yet explored.

However, if I am implementing an explored set for the purpose of avoiding duplicates it seems contradictory that I allow them in certain instances.

I believe the real error may lie in a lack of thorough understanding of the algorithm and I am sincerely hoping for some assistance, thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by "less optimal goal node"? Do you have multiple possible goals? Does distance matter? If so, DFS is not the right algorithm to start with.

Comment: You're welcome, my program does not support multiple goals but take the example I used below for instance. The first 'b' would be adjacent to the start node, thus the path length would be 1 but the second 'b' (same node but encountered along a longer path) would have a path length > 1. That is what I refer to as 'less optimal.' 

The program is meant for an assignment and I am required to implement breadth first, depth first, and iterative deepening so its suitability isn't a factor in whether its implemented. However, this is proving to be a road block as I need complete this before ITDS

Comment: Okay. Well, DFS is what we have discussed below, it is generally used to expand an entire graph or search for a single node (sometimes for cycle detection). As soon as you want shortest paths etc, you need to look into other algorithms. For your assignment of implementing DFS however, just make the change discussed (do not repush visited nodes) and you're fine!

Comment: @us2012 Don't ask people to accept your answers, it's not what the comments are for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The algorithm commonly known as depth first search does *not* need a "frontier", as you call it. This concept is used however with A* graph searches (it is usually called "open set" there).

For standard depth first search, all you need is a stack of nodes: Push the initial node on the stack, then in each step pop one node from the stack, examine it and push all its neighbours(*) on top of the stack. Then, repeat.

(*) remember to mark all nodes that you push on the stack as visited (I believe you call this "explored set" in your questions) and don't push nodes that have already been visited.

By using a stack, you avoid the problem you describe.

If you actually want to maintain that frontier/open set, make sure that it never contains duplicates: use a data structure that does not allow duplicates (e.g. a `set`).

(Sidenote: If your graph nodes have a natural numbering and you expect your DFS to visit the majority of notes, you may as well use an `array`/`vector` for your explored set/closed set.)

Comment: First off, thanks for answering. My program uses the push and pop methods made available by linked blocking deque so effectively I am using it as a stack

Here I am really only using the name frontier/open list to refer to what you are describing, but probably I should give an example to make the problem clearer: 

Imagine: 1. examine a
         2. a is not the goal node so expand 'a' (expansion leads to     b and c)
         3. b and c are pushed onto the stack
         4. b happens to be the goal node but c is explored first
         5. in expansion of the paths leading from c b is met again

Comment: @user2012620 `b` may be met again, but you don't push it onto the stack again because you have marked `b` as visited when you first pushed it onto the stack.

Comment: Well thank you, that was really the source of my confusion, see as we have not actually examined b, only added it to the frontier for examination after backtracking (because if we knew it was the goal we would not ever have continued the search) I was unsure as to whether the algorithm should return the second 'b' met as the goal rather than the first 'b', note this is impossible if it never allowed the second 'b' to be pushed onto the stack.

Comment: @user2012620 Glad I could help - I'm still not convinced we solved the underlying problem though. I suspect that you actually don't want DFS at all, see my comment under your question.